# Getting the value of HTML tags with nodejs on an external page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to get the values all HTML elements with the class "objectModifier" in a webpage using nodejs. What is best way to get HTML and parse the tags?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio):

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
let $ = cheerio.load('<p class="objectModifier"></p>');
// then use $('.objectModifier') to select
```

Comment: OP can use something like [needle](https://github.com/tomas/needle) or [request](https://github.com/request/request) to get the html easily

Answer (score 1):

Use [cheerio](http://npmjs.com/package/cheerio) for nodejs for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to go with https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio to parse the HTML and find all objects with class "objectModifier" using its ".find('.objectModifier')" function

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to perform this task. Please refer to example below

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
jsdom.env({
    file: "some file.html",
    done: function (err, window) {
        GLOBAL.window = window;
        GLOBAL.document = window.document;
        showAllElements();
    }
});
function showAllElements() {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".objectModifier");
    console.log("there are ", elements.length, " elements with class objectModifier").
}
```